# Understanding relations and where make relations on table Microsoft Dynamics Ax 2012

Tags: microsoft-dynamics

I am new on MS Dynamics World.
I have relationship one to more.
In which table I have to make relations? On child table or on parent table?
[My situation example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AbswY.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer for this question I found here

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oe534o9fodU&index=79&list=PLWSxgDbjVWTjxvgnaAZ0iK8o5dYHAYhrq&t=0s